# How to install the `imap.so` for PHP?

Tags: php, imap

This is a bash of install PHP in GitHub:

```
install_php()
{
    local configure_str=$(cat <<EOF
./configure \
            --prefix=/usr/local/php-${php_version} \
            --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-${php_version}/etc \
            --enable-fpm \
            --with-fpm-user=www \
            --with-fpm-group=www \
            --with-mysqli \
            --with-pdo-mysql \
            --with-libdir=lib64 \
            --with-iconv-dir \
            --with-freetype-dir \
            --with-jpeg-dir \
            --with-png-dir \
            --with-zlib \
            --with-libxml-dir=/usr \
            --enable-xml \
            --disable-rpath  \
            --enable-bcmath \
            --enable-shmop \
            --enable-sysvsem \
            --enable-inline-optimization \
            --with-curl \
            --enable-mbregex \
            --enable-mbstring \
            --enable-ftp \
            --with-gd \
            --enable-gd-native-ttf \
            --with-openssl \
            --with-mhash \
            --enable-pcntl \
            --enable-sockets \
            --enable-opcache \
            --with-xmlrpc \
            --enable-zip \
            --enable-soap \
            --without-pear \
            --with-gettext \
            --disable-fileinfo \
            --enable-maintainer-zts \
            --with-kerberos \  # the --with-kerberos is added by me
            --with-imap-ssl    # the --with-imap-ssl is added by me
EOF
)
    cd $basepath

    tar -zxvf php-${php_version}.tar.gz
    cd ./php-${php_version}
    $configure_str
    make 
    make install

    # create a link to php
    ln -sf /usr/local/php-${php_version}/bin/php /usr/local/bin/

    # write php-fpm configure
    cat > /usr/local/php-${php_version}/etc/php-fpm.conf <<EOF
```

I want to install the imap php, so I add the `--with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl` in the bash, and I also installed the `libc-client-devel`:

```
yum install -y uw-imap-devel libc-client
ln -s /usr/lib64/libc-client.so /usr/lib/libc-client.so
```

but after I installed the PHP(execute `./install.sh` for PHP), in the

```
/usr/local/php-7.1.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/
```

there  only have:

```
opcache.a  opcache.so
```

there is no `imap.so`.

How to install the `imap.so` for PHP?

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried add the `--with-imap`, then re-run the `./install.sh`, but still do not have the `imap.so` generated in the dir.

Comment: [IMAP::Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/imap.installation.php) : "To get these functions to work, you have to compile PHP with --with-imap[=DIR] "

Comment: @hassan See my edit.